# Обновить данные на панели

Tags: javascript, extjs

Как перезагрузить панель не перезагружая страницу? Мне просто нужно обновлять данные по клику. Пробовал

```
Ext.get('mypanel').refresh();
Ext.get('mypanel').doLayout(); 
Ext.get('mypanel').reload();
```

В логах пишет что это не функция делать ничего не будет

Comment: надо вызывать myPanel.update()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Юзаем `JQuery`: меняем значения и/или атрибуты самих полей на панели в контроллере или где у вас там функции прописываются:

```
$(".fieldClass").text(variable);

//или свойства атрибутов к примеру
$(".imgFieldClass").attr('src', path);
```